# IsNull Always Returns True

Tags: ms-access, vba

The function `IsNull(char)` in my below code is always returning true. Why?

StrText is getting it from a text field and the value is:

```
strText = +  96666
```

The particular section that is giving me an issue:

```
 If intCounter = 1 And strChar = "+" Then
            For Count = intCounter + 1 To Len(strText)
                Char = Mid(strText, Count, 1)
                If IsNull(Char) = True Then
                    Count = Count + 1
                End If
                If IsNumeric(Char) And Char <> "0" Then
                    Exit For
                    MsgBox "Problem"
                End If
            Next Count
        End If
```

the complete function is:

```
Public Function NumbersOnly(ByVal strText As String) As Boolean
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim strChar As String
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Char As String
    strText = Trim(strText)
    For intCounter = 1 To Len(strText)
        strChar = Mid(strText, intCounter, 1)
        If intCounter = 1 And IsNumeric(strChar) = False And strChar <> "+" Then
            NumbersOnly = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        If intCounter = 1 And strChar = "+" Then
            For Count = intCounter + 1 To Len(strText)
                Char = Mid(strText, Count, 1)
                If IsNull(Char) = True Then
                    Count = Count + 1
                End If
                If IsNumeric(Char) And Char <> "0" Then
                    Exit For
                    MsgBox "Problem"
                End If
            Next Count
        End If
        If intCounter <> 1 And (IsNumeric(strChar) = False And strChar <> " ") Then
            NumbersOnly = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next intCounter
    NumbersOnly = True
End Function
```

Comment: Might I suggest looking into [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) - they make this sort of validation task remarkably easy!

Answer (score 3):

Strings are initialized to an *empty string*, not null or nothing.

Consider the following subroutine:

```
Sub test()
    Dim char As String

    If IsNull(char) Then
        Debug.Print "I can't get here."
    ElseIf char = "" Then
        Debug.Print "HELLO THERE!"
    End If

    char = "sometext"
    If IsNull(char) Then
        Debug.Print "I can't get here."
    ElseIf char = "" Then
        Debug.Print "Now this fails too"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Hello Again."
    End If
End Sub
```

In short, you don't want to check to see if your `char` variable is null, you want to check to see if it's an empty string.

Comment: But his function seems always to be null as IsNull returns true.

Comment: @David I clarified my answer.

Comment: I think emilios may be trying to skip the space in the string he supplied "+ 96666", so instead he may want to check for " ".

Comment: 1) if your are just checking for an empty string checking for `Len(char) = 0` is actually more efficient.
2) +1 @ckuhn203 for converting `IsNull(char) = True` to just `IsNull(char)`

Comment: @LimaNightHawk Really? Do you know of any documentation or tests to prove that? That's interesting.

Comment: @ckuhn203 [Here is a good explanation](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html) of why it is faster.  Using an immediate String value like "" requires that VBA actually creates the blank string in memory (4 bytes to hold the length, plus a couple bytes per unicode character), wasting time and memory.  Technically you could do `char = vbNullString` which would be faster because `vbNullString` is a constant value that already exists at runtime for such purposes, so you incur no memory or time costs for creation.  However, `LenB(char) = 0` is probably fastest.

Comment: (Unless you're doing the comparison a lot, it's probably not worth the loss in readability though)

Comment: The readability is definitely a primary factor. I've used `Len` for so long, that for me it's become instinctive: I just always do the quick `If Len(myString) Then` --but that's not much help to anyone else who has to read my code. Point conceded.
Oh, and now I'll be using `LenB` :)

Comment: @Blackhawk Just for future readers.... you have to be careful with `vbNullString` because it is not the same thing as an empty string. This is confusing to a lot of people.